# How to get a single variable in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am running a competition which is based on WP Custom Fields. I am trying to count all meta values of a meta_key='odd' for a specific user. I am using the formula below but it's not returning any result.

```
$meta_key = 'odd';
$post_author = 'Admin';
$odd = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT Count(meta_value)
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta->post_id = $wpdb->posts->ID
    WHERE $wpdb->postmeta->meta_key = 'odd' AND $wpdb->posts->post_author = 'Admin'
    ",
    $meta_key, $post_author
) );
echo "<p>Total odd {$odd}</p>";
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the post_author is the id of the author not the username

Comment: I changed the $post_author = '1' -> ID number and still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up the `$wpdb` variables and the `$post` variables - for your `JOIN`, for example, you can't use `$wpdb->postmeta->post_id`, it would be `{$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id`, and would be even better to just use table aliases. Your `prepare()` is also not passing in your `meta_key` or `author` because you don't have `%s` placeholders for them

```
$odd = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT count(meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE pm.meta_key = %s AND p.post_author = %s
    ",
    $meta_key, $post_author
) );
```